# Add property binding programmatically instead of template

Tags: angular, data-binding

I am trying to understand if this is possible or not in Angular.
Instead of defining a control binding in template:

```
<button [disabled]="helper.disabled"></button>
```

Can I send the control, without any binding defined in the template, to a helper class and set the binding there?

The code example below does not work. It does not set up a working databinding that later can be used in randomMethod() to change the disabled state of the button.

Have I just set the binding in wrong lifecycle or misunderstood something else?

```
// ***** my-component.html ****************
...
<button #myButton></button>
...


// ***** my-component.ts ****************
...
@ViewChild('myButton') myButton: Button;
protected helper: Helper;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.helper = new Helper();
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.helper.initButton(this.myButton);
  this.cdref.detectChanges();
}

...


// ***** helper.ts ****************

public disabled boolean;

public initButton(button:Button): void{
  button.disabled = this.disabled; // <-- HOW TO?
}

private randomMethod(){
  this.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ViewChild gives an ElementRef, using the native element property of the ElementRef you can set the disabled property

```js
// Component
@ViewChild('myButton') myButton: ElementRef;

// Helper
public initButton(button: ElementRef): void {
  button.nativeElement.disabled = this.disabled;
}
```